# how to let users upload their custom cover image

Tags: javascript, users, html

I have a dashboard for users (one page using elementor and buddyboss to change stuff like name profile pic etc). I want users to be able to upload a custom cover image. I found some code that almost works

```
<input type="file" id="image-input" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/jpg">
<div id="display-image"></div>

<style>
#display-image{
  width: 400px;
  height: 225px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
</style>

<script>
const image_input = document.querySelector("#image-input");

image_input.addEventListener("change", function() {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
    const uploaded_image = reader.result;
    document.querySelector("#display-image").style.backgroundImage = `url(${uploaded_image})`;
  });
  reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});
</script>
```

The issue is that it doesn't save so you have to put the image in every time the page reloads. There might also be an issue of changing the whole page instead of per user but I can't test that right now

Comment: how is the cover image stored on the server side? There is nothing to persist save or store your cover image here, and no uploading. Is there an existing cover image feature? And where are you placing this code? Keep in mind that Elementor/Buddyboss/3rd party plugin dev support questions are offtopic here and not in this stacks scope

Comment: I have no idea where it's stored or how to control that. I don't understand your second statement. The only possible way to upload a cover image is the buddyboss members page which I'm trying to move away from cause I can't modify it. I'm placing the code in elementor (html widget) as one block of code as it seems to work there but I do have access to ftp if needed. Oh sorry didn't realise this was off topic would there be a better place for my question?

Comment: The best place to get help is from the Elementor devs. As weird as it may sound, the main Stack Exchange is another alternative. Just make sure to tag your question as `wordpress` and `elementor` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress+elementor